# Set condition for mass action checkbox visibility in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, custom-options, module

I have a magento module that I'm developing for importing products into magento.
I Have a grid where the user can select his products, and import them all (Mass Action).
If the user has products already imported in the list, then it's shown in the grid, but the user shouldn't select it (check it's product checkbox) to avoid re-importing the product.

My question is, how can I add a condition for a mass action checkbox visibility ?

Here is my Grid's _prepareMassaction:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('sku');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('import');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('import', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('import')->__('Import'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massImport'),
        'confirm' => Mage::helper('import')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

Any Help someone ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should change your approach. Removing or hiding the row selector checkbox should be avoided as there might be (one day) additional mass actions that the row is applicable to.

Instead, as you apparently have the information whether to omit a row or not, you should just skip it during your import routine and present a notification to the user like

> The following products were imported before: [list of product names /
>   ids].